# How can I use IIS URL Rewrite to prevent people from linking or leeching images on a website?

Tags: regex, iis

I came across the features of IIS and it notes that I can prevent inline linking or leeching. How can I implement such a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use URL rewrite to point to a resource within a web application that will be able to identify the refferer before displaying the resource to the client which called the application.

IE, rewrite the following
/images/myPhoto.JPG
to
/getResource.PHP?resource=%2Fimages%2FmyPhoto.JPG

Then inside getResource.PHP 
forgive me if this isn't quite right, my php is a little sketchy, but you get the idea

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if( /*test that it fits your criteria*/ true ) {
        $imagepath= $_GET['resource'];
    } else {
        $imagepath= "/images/stopLeaching.JPG";
    }
} else {
    $imagepath= $_GET['resource'];
}

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);

imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: So there is no way I get can IIS to identify the referer?

Comment: Yes, but its somewhat more difficult than an application side solution, and I personally have never done it in a stable production environment (not for lack of trying). 

I do know for a fact though, that it has nothing to do with URL Rewriting, and is actually a matter of installing Referer Authentication, which is just a custom Insecure Authentication Protocol. There is a few blogs out there telling you how you can do this, but take it from me, with 10 years development experience, its a nightmare to implement.